# conceived of as vs. conceived as

Tags: phrases, verbs, word-usage, prepositions

When I want to write that some *something* has been "taken to mean" or "understood" or "interpreted as" *XYZ*, I sometimes use the phrase "to conceive of *something* as *XYZ*, where *XYZ* usually is a longer and detailed explanation.

So, I often end up having a sentence like this:

> *Something* has been conceived of as *XYZ*.

My supervisor, when reading my drafts, always marks this as wrong and wants me to get rid of "of", so that the sentence would read:

> *Something* has been conceived as *XYZ*.

While trusting my supervisor with his native speaker intuition and his really good knowledge of grammar et al., I still feel that the sentence requires the "of". It sounds terrible to me.

Anybody in for a verdict on this?

Comment: If I felt compelled to use passive voice at all in instances like this one, I would probably use "understood" or "interpreted" and avoid "conceived/conceived of" altogether. But I recommend that you specify who is doing the conceiving. "Most practitioners understand _something_ to mean _XYZ_." "Some experts have interpreted _something_ to mean _XYZ_." When authors explicitly identify the actors responsible for the actions they're discussing, readers benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with JLG's explanation. Your supervisor is conflating two similar-looking but non-identical constructions having two different meanings:

1) To conceive *of* X *as* Y, where *conceive* means **to interpret / comprehend**:

> Copernicus conceived *of* the Earth *as* a sphere rather than as a plane

2) To conceive X *as* Y, where *conceive* means **to invent**, especially when the  invention is in pursuit of a particular objective:

> Julius Edgar Lilienfeld conceived the field-effect transistor *as* a solid-state replacement for the triode.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're answering the question asked. Do you agree with the supervisor or not? Links to your definitions would improve your answer. Also, your two parts just illustrate the point that *conceive* can be a transitive verb (taking an object) and an intransitive. I don't think your second example sentence is equivalent to the OP's example. *Conceive* has a lot of definitions.